# MongoDB and PHP frameworks

Tags: php, frameworks, mongodb

Apart from Lithium, Vork and F3 what other frameworks **natively** support mongodb?

I've seen the list on mongodb.org. Wanted to know if there were any newer ones they missed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

full list is on http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Libraries,+Frameworks,+and+Tools#

Comment: yes, but new ones keep popping up. wanted to know if they missed any.

Comment: @Eva611 - you writing a book about MongoDB or you want to use one of the framwork to program ?

Comment: A little bit of both. Exploring PHP / MongoDB interactions for a class.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lightweight one that I've assembled. It's basically an object wrapper, something to easily map an object to a DB collection.

https://github.com/gatesvp/MongoModel

The docs are not quite there, but just take a look at the unit tests to get an idea for basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

ProdigyView has Mongo Support 
http://www.prodigyview.com/tutorials/slideshare/417/99